# Make cell view unavailable color

Tags: ios, swift, human-interface

[image]

How to make cell unavailable view like in Settings app on the screen?

Comment: Set alpha value to 0.5 for any view.

Comment: That picture is huge! Can you please shrink it a little to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below code in `cellForRowAt indexPath`:

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

for view in cell.subviews {
    view.alpha = 0.5
}
```